# Did lord Krishna tell Arjuna that all the names (such as Rudra, Indra) refer to Krishna only?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

I have found many people saying that all the names found in vedas and upanishads ( like Agni, Aditya, Rudra, Indra, etc.) refer to Krishna only; and Lord Krishna himself told this to Arjuna in the Mahabharata.

So my question is if it is so, then in which chapter is it mentioned and about what is the conversation between Lord Krishna and Arjuna?

Answer (score 3):

> Sarve veda padam amananti, tapamsi sarvani-ca yad vdanti Yad  icchanto brahmacharyam caranti, tat te padam samgrahenabravimi om iti etat
>
> All the words in veda refer to same, all the tapsvi say the same, it gives whatever the wishes of brahmachari that is the same as OM. 
>  - Katha Upanishad 2.15 sloka

In Geetha he refers to OM vibuthi adhyaya

> maharṣīṇāṃ bhṛgurahaṃ girāmasmyekamakṣaram।
> yajñānāṃ japayajño'smi sthāvarāṇāṃ himālayaḥ ।10.25
>
> Of great sages I am Bhrigu. Of sounds I am the monosyllabic mantra Om. Of sacrifices I am japa. Of immovable things I am the Himalayas.

> सर्वस्य चाहं हृदि सन्निविष्टो
> मत्त: स्मृतिर्ज्ञानमपोहनं च |
> वेदैश्च सर्वैरहमेव वेद्यो
> वेदान्तकृद्वेदविदेव चाहम् || 15||
>
> sarvasya chāhaṁ hṛidi sanniviṣhṭo
> mattaḥ smṛitir jñānam apohanaṁ cha
> vedaiśh cha sarvair aham eva vedyo
> vedānta-kṛid veda-vid eva chāham
>
> BG 15.15: I am seated in the hearts of all living beings, and from Me come memory, knowledge, as well as forgetfulness. I alone am to be known by all the Vedas, am the author of the Vedānt, and the knower of the meaning of the Vedas.

By induction a->b  Krishna -> OM single letter By katha upanishad All words are OM Krishna-> OM <- All words in Veda(Katha upanishad) in other words Krishna -> all words in veda -> OM is same.  This was stated by madvacharya. Madvacharya even goes further all the sounds refer to him only not only veda..
Jai Madhva gurave namaha.. Jai sri krishna

Comment: Agni -> one which makes water to move -> its the chetana sakthi for jiva to move, otherwise jiva has no action.. he cannot move by himself so Agni is Lord inside a chetan that is man or animal <BR> Indra who is lord indirya (That is again God) <BR> Rudra Destructive fire which can consume the universe. that is lord inside rudra that is nrsimha..

Answer (score 0):

All the names belong to Bhagawān Shiva and also originated from him.

> 7. In Kāla mind is fixed, in Kāla breath (is fixed), in Kāla names (are fixed/composed); when Kāla has arrived all these creatures rejoice. (ATHARVANA VEDA 19:53).

> Initially Mahesvara created the names and forms of creatures as per the provisions of the Vedas. (Linga Puran 1.70.258b-259a).

> 3. From Kāla the Riks arose, the Yagus was born from Kāla; Kāla put forth the sacrifice, the imperishable share of the gods. (ATHARVANA VEDA 19.54).

> 27. All the names belongs to Rudra. (Ashvalayana Grihya Sutra 4.9).

All the names of Lord Vishnu/Krishna etc are that if Bhagawān Shiva's only.

> Whatever names you have oh Govinda, they are my (Maheshwara's) names only without doubt. (MBH H.P. 3.88).

Again,

> Sri Kurma Rupi Vishnu said:- The Supreme Lord (Maheshwara) is the Supreme, the unmanifest, the fourfold vyuha forms (Vasudeva, Sankarṣaṇa, Pradyumna, Aniruddha), the eternal (Sanatana).
> He is infinite and immeasurable and the controller and omnipresent. (Kurma Purana 4.5).
> .
>
> (Shiva) is Hari because he destroys everything, is said to be Swayambhu because he is not produced and is prior to all. He is called Narayana because he is the final destination of all beings. He is called Hara because he destroys bondage. Being omnipresent/all pervading, Shiva is called Vishnu. (Kurma Purana 4.60-61).

Yes, the names are applicable to Lord Krishna also because.:

> “Kesava is that devoted worshipper of Rudra who has sprung from Rudra himself. Kesava always worship the Lord Siva, regarding his Phallic emblem to be the origin of the universe." (MBH 7:172:89-90).

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Question is about finding related verse from text like Mahabharata where conversation between Krishna and Arjuna happened

Comment: OP asked "if it is so.?" So, i gave answer based on why so or why not. Just like the answer above. If necessary, i can add verses from b.g. etc. also.